# Is Twitter Bootstrap supposed to have support for toasts?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On starting to implement my own toasts, I have discovered they are invisible, because Bootstrap CSS contains a declaration for `.toast` (which among other things sets its opacity to zero).

But Bootstrap's website shows no results when searching for `toast`, nor does the javascript bundle file contain the string `toast`. I don't know if this could be something leftover from Bootstrap 3, but the documentation for 3.3.7 also doesn't contain the string `toast` anywhere on their Components nor Javascript page.

I am unsure if it's okay for me to delete that part of the CSS file, or it may break some other component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented in the [v4.2 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/) under Components. Are you searching in the wrong Bootstrap 4 documentation?

Comment: he not, he using v3. And yes, he might upgrade the version

Comment: @Wolfzmus He does not say, but I'm assuming he is running some version of Bootstrap 4. He's using the `bootstrap-4`-tag and is suspecting that it is something "left over" from Bootstrap 3.

Comment: For whatever reason, the suggestions popup didn't come up when i searched "toast" on the docs (it does now). But i was mostly perplexed (and still am) that there was no string "toast" in their javascript code, so I used that as my "confirmation" that something was wrong... Anyway, my bad for a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can, here the documentation bootstrap for toast 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/

EDIT : probably you need upgrade your bootstrap version